# Trigger for both insert and update

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger that will prevent a user from inserting to or updating the quantity in my orderLines table if the amount is greater than the quantity on the products table.

Is there a way to do it in a single trigger or do I have to create to separate ones for both insert and update actions?

Below is how my trigger starts:

```
CREATE TRIGGER OrdersLines_ITrig
ON ordersLines
FOR INSERT
AS
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the `BEGIN/END` blocks:

Triggers have special `INSERTED` and `DELETED` tables to track "before" and "after" data. So you can use something like `IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DELETED)` to detect an update. You only have rows in `DELETED` on update, but there are always rows in `INSERTED`.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.TriggerName
ON dbo.TableName
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted) AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted)
    BEGIN     
      ----Do update
    END;

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Inserted) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted)
    BEGIN
      -----Do insert
    END;
END
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple requirement you can handle using CHECK CONSTRAINT itself. If you are defining trigger, you have to properly rollback the transaction. Have proper error message etc. You can simply have a check constraint, which will do all these things for you.

I would suggest you to do below steps:

1. Create a user defined function, which returns TRUE or FALSE, based on the quantity in the Product table.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION CheckQuantity(@productID INT)
    RETURNS BIT
    AS
    BEGIN
    ---LOGIC 
    END
```

2. Leverage the user defined function in the CHECK constraint.

```sql
ALTER TABLE OrderLines ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_Quantity CHECK( dbo.CheckQuantity(ProductId) = = 1)
```